# Javascript charts not populating data from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am attempting to query a mysql table for info to use the data to populate the chart but I am getting an x axis with "clothing undefined" running across it and the bars are not populating.

I am using the following script to query the table
clothing.php:

```
    if($_GET['action'] == 'clothingOrdered' && $_GET['id']){
$uid = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT clothing, orders FROM clothingOrder WHERE userid = '$uid'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
if($query){
$data = array();
foreach($query as $row){
$data[] = $row;

}

print json_encode($data);

}else{
echo mysqli_error($db_conx);

}



}else{
print 'not good';

}
```

This yields:

[{"clothing":"tshirt ","orders":"4"},{"clothing":"jeans","orders":"7"},{"clothing":"hats","orders":"34"},{"clothing":"dresses","orders":"12"},{"clothing":"jackets","orders":"27"},{"clothing":"sweaters","orders":"23"}]

Area for graph:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Js file for the data:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var id = $('#intro').data('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: '../php_parsers/clothing.php?action=clothingOrdered&id='+id,
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var clothing = [];
            var orders = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                clothing.push("Clothing " + data[i].clothing);
                orders.push(data[i].orders);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: clothing,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'Clothing ordered',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: orders
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#myChart");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I also have the following scripts included in my page where the chart is:

```
        <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Any feedback is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Are there any JS errors? I created this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bcoLjd6/)  with the data you're supposed to be loading and the chart renders as expected (including the X axis).

Comment: No the only error I get is related to bootstrap. I guess I should maybe try it again

Comment: Also I get 7 "clothing undefined" even though there are only 6

Comment: Works for me using your data and code: https://codepen.io/skunkbad/pen/prLgEQ

Comment: Could it be that your ajax config doesn't specify a dataType? I normally declare `dataType: 'json'` if I'm expecting json. jQuery docs say that if not present it will try to intelligently guess the datatype, but I've seen it not do that many times before.

Comment: @BrianGottier would you be able to submit that as an answer? That was my issue. I would like to uproot it and mark it as the answer. Thank you

Comment: @Blanco, I just turned it into an answer. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to set the dataType parameter for the AJAX request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../php_parsers/clothing.php?action=clothingOrdered&id='+id,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        // ...
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```